# Cannot change power settings despite being local administrator

Tags: windows-7

I'm on Windows 7. My user account is member of the administrators group, so should have the privileges to change anything.
However when I go in to:

Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options\System Settings

The resulting dialog box has a yellow banner mentioning:

"some settings are managed by your system administrator".

And I can't change any setting.

Why? And what can I do about this?

Comment: Is this machine part of a domain?

Comment: Yes. I suspect it has to do with group policies, however the doain administrator has been trying to fix this for a month now, so I guess I'll have to find a way to help myself here.